# Drupal 7 : global $user does not work

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, global-variables

I am working on a Drupal module,trying to get `uname` and `uid` of the global variable `$user`: if `$user` is used within .module file it works but if not I get :  `Trying to get property of non-object in ... on line 377` and  `var_dump($user)` gives `null` ,
here is my code :

MyModuleAPI.php:

```
function get_DB_Handler($projectname)
{  
    global $user;
    $u_name = $user->name;
    $u_id = $user->uid; //line 377
...
}
```

this function is called after an ajax POST query.

I will be grateful if someone clarify for me where is the difference since all files are in the same module. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this php file included into module code? This global is defined when Drupal bootstraps.

Comment: no it is not, do I have to?

Comment: @ouou Why wouldn't you?

Comment: No @Jack I don't need it there (in .module) , it is used to accomplish ajax query functions.

Comment: I would recommend learning how to do ajax posts within your module. Then if you really need to call an outside php library from within your module.

Answer (score 0):

`$user` global variable is defined when Drupal bootstraps. You must call appropriate functions from the core to make it visible inside non-module code. Put the following to the beginning of you file:

```
<?php
$file_path = dirname(__FILE__);
$path = preg_replace('/sites.*/', "", $file_path);
//adjust the path to your website root directory
$path = substr_replace($path ,"",-1);

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'site_hostname';

require_once($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'includes' .  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Comment: Thank you @user4035, I gave it a try but there is a problem by including bootstrap it increase time response, so I think I should get user parameters from javascript and pass them in variables.

Comment: @ouou Javascript is vulnerable if you have some restrictions for users, but this is an option. Look at this doc: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7. Try to decrease the bootstrapping level until `$user` is defined. Maybe, it will decrease the time.

Comment: `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION` is required here and it is true it reduces time response, but I don't know why it didn't give me the current `$user` but an anonymous with 0 as id.

Comment: btw with Javascript option I used  `drupal_add_js($setting, 'setting'); ` after defining my own setting and call it later within `Drupal.behaviors` , after all it is a user name and his id to be stored, is it insecure?

Comment: @ouou What if somebody passes the id of the admin?

Comment: yes you have right , I will keep it for now temporarily until I find a better solution, thank you @user4035 for your precious help.